# Physics - put circles inside circle bounding layout, how to achieve it?

Tags: android, box2d, physics, boundary

i am using https://github.com/Jawnnypoo/PhysicsLayout  library for implement physics layout to achieve animation within the circle boundary, but there does not appear to be a way to create a  boundary with circle. I'm looking to put circle views inside a circular bounding layout.

**Anyone has idea how to achieve circle bounding layout?**

Comment: Have you considered creating your bounding circle with a connected chain shape that approximates a circular shape?